# Unbelevable JSON behaviour occuerd while passing the JSON parameters

Tags: android, json

i am trying to pass three parameters to an JSON object. after that i have pass that object and the URL of the WebService to get the Json object from that Service. my Webservice takes 3 parameters Accordingly long x string y long z . i am put my parameters using

```
JsonObject.put("name",value);
```

the problem is : According to my method it should pass the three parameters like this

```
{x:52,y:"51,54",z:10}
```

but i got unfortunately like below. the order is completely wrong. i dont know why i am getting like this.

```
{y:"51,54",x:52,z:10}
```

my string parameter goes to the first index and other two are also in wrong order.

im posting my code below...

this is the place where i put my parameters to the json object

```
     public String getResponceFromServer(String apptRequestId,String apptRequestList,String userID){

     String responce = null;
     String returnVal = null;

     String URL ="myUrl";
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

     try {
        JsonParser jpar = new JsonParser();
        JSONObject userParam = new JSONObject();



        userParam.put("apptRequestId", apptRequestId);
        userParam.put("apptRequestList", apptRequestList);
        userParam.put("userId",userID);
        json = jpar.getJSONFromUrl(userParam,URL);


        responce = json.getString("d");
        //read caregiverPerson id , 
        /*if(responce.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            returnVal = "-1";
        }

        else{
            returnVal = "0";
        }*/


     } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        // createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
     }



     return responce;

 }
```

here the method for get the json object for a given URL and the parameters

```
 public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(JSONObject parm,String url) throws JSONException {


         InputStream is = null;
         JSONObject jObj = null;
         String json = "";
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            /*JSONObject parm = new JSONObject();
            parm.put("agencyId", 27);
            parm.put("caregiverPersonId", 47);*/

        /*  if(!(jObj.isNull("d"))){
                jObj=null;
            }
            */


            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            HttpEntity body = new StringEntity(parm.toString(), "utf8");
            httpPost.setEntity(body);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

}

can someone tell me where is the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

JSON properties can be in any order. There's no problem.

Internally, `JSONObject` stores them in a `HashMap` and then writes them out in an order the `keys()` come out, not in the order they're put there. ([Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20080701/org/json/JSONObject.java))

Comment: so how can i get my json object as i expected...?

Comment: If you're posting the JSON to an API that expects the properties to be in a specific order, that API is broken and should be fixed.

Comment: no i just pass the parameter for a simple web service.. it just takes my parameters and gives string responce..can you guide me to pass my parameters as i wanted ?

Comment: Your question has the incorrect premise that the order is wrong. It's not. The two JSON representations are semantically identical. So, what's the actual problem?

Comment: problem is i want an Ordered json object...as an example if i want to pass like this : {x:44, y:11,z:45} the json object also should like this..but i got like this : {y:11,x:44,z:45}